# Add infinite scroll to content splitted post

Tags: pages, javascript, navigation, content

I'm using `<!--nextpage-->` tag to split up the post content into multiple pages. My example post content looks like this:

```
<img src="1.jpg" alt=""/><!--nextpage-->
<img src="2.jpg" alt=""/><!--nextpage-->
<img src="3.jpg" alt=""/><!--nextpage-->
<img src="4.jpg" alt=""/>
```

I want to setup infinite scrolling so when a user scrolls down the page it'll load the next image/content of the post. Is there a way to do this? There are lots of tutorials on adding infinite scrolling to posts but they only load more posts where as I want to load more of the post content

Comment: And what have you tried? There is tons of stuff out there on how to set this up.

Comment: @Nath there are lots of stuff but all of them are for loading more posts. What I want is to load the the next content of the post since it has been split up into multiple pages

Comment: Well this seems related to [this](http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/a/235959/99217). It would essentially be the same thing, but you would call your ajax on page `scroll` event instead of `click`. There would be a check for page length and event would fire when we reach x % of that page.

Comment: Use the a combination of a waypoints JS library with https://wordpress.org/plugins/json-rest-api/. You're looking for a full AJAX+CSS solution. >>> When element is visible, fetch content and display. Pretty simple.

Comment: See: http://imakewebthings.com/waypoints/api/waypoint/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your best bet is to use a combination of JS [waypoint](http://imakewebthings.com/waypoints/api/waypoint/) libraries with the WP [Rest API](https://wordpress.org/plugins/json-rest-api/).

When element is visible, fetch content and display. Pretty simple.

Instead of the `<nextpage>` you could also wrap this in a custom [shortcode](https://codex.wordpress.org/Shortcode_API) but this is primarily a JS problem, not really a WP issue.

Comment: https://camwiegert.github.io/in-view/