# Load post content into div with ajax

Tags: posts, images, ajax, links, content

I'm currently using `<!––nextpage––>` to split my content into multiple pages. This is what my example post content looks like:

```
<a href="http://linktopage.com/2/"><img src="blah1.jpg" alt=""/></a><!--nextpage-->
<a href="http://linktopage.com/3/"><img src="blahab.jpg" alt=""/></a><!--nextpage-->
<a href="http://linktopage.com/4/"><img src="blahco.jpg" alt=""/></a><!--nextpage-->
<a href="http://linktopage.com/5/"><img src="blahneat.jpg" alt=""/></a>
```

Basically all the images are hyperlinked to the next page. When the user clicks on the image I want the next page to be loaded inside the existing div via ajax.

How can I do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are asking to load the *next page* but it doesn't make sense to load the entire page if all you want is the image. The following will do just that.

**The HTML**

At a minimum add a wrapper div to isolate the image we want to replace and so it's possible to search in our ajax response for the new image we want to use to replace the current one.

```
<div class="image-wrap"><a class="ajax-load-next" href="http://linktopage.com/2/"><img src="blah1.jpg" alt=""/></a></div><!--nextpage-->
<div class="image-wrap"><a class="ajax-load-next" href="http://linktopage.com/3/"><img src="blahab.jpg" alt=""/></a></div><!--nextpage-->
<div class="image-wrap"><a class="ajax-load-next" href="http://linktopage.com/4/"><img src="blahco.jpg" alt=""/></a></div><!--nextpage-->
<div class="image-wrap"><a class="ajax-load-next" href="http://linktopage.com/5/"><img src="blahneat.jpg" alt=""/></a></div>
```

**The Javascript**

This should be placed in your existing `$(document).ready(function(){ ... });` function

```
$('body').on('click', '.image-wrap', function(e) { // listen for 'click' on our '.image-wrap' element
  e.preventDefault();  // Prevents default behavior on the a element

  $.ajax({

    url: $(this).find( 'a' ).attr( 'href' ), // the url we are fetching by ajax
    success: function (response) {

      newImg = $(response).find('.image-wrap').html(), // get the new href link and image from the response, contained in div.image-wrap

      $( 'div.image-wrap' ).html( newImg ); // set the new html for our inner div

    }
  }).fail(function (data) {

    if ( window.console && window.console.log ) {

      console.log( data );  // log failure to console

    }

  });

});
```

**EDIT**

to add a script via [`wp_enqueue_script`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/wp_enqueue_script/) just add this to your **functions.php**

```
add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts' 'my_custom_js');
function my_custom_js(){
  wp_enqueue_script( 'main-js', get_stylesheet_directory_uri() . '/js/main.js' , array( 'jquery' ), '1.0.0', true );
}
```

then in your **themes folder** create a file `main.js` in a `js` folder and then add to it the javascript code above. the file should be located in `theme_folder/js/main.js` and the above script should be loaded in document ready

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  // Script
});
```

the parameters of the `wp_enqueue_script` function are as follow

- Param 1: script handle. should be a unique name and is used to identify the script you are loading. For instance, if you need to deregister the script you would call `wp_dequeue_script` and use this handle.
- Param 2: the location of the file you are loading
- Param 3: an array of dependencies for this file (files that should be loaded before, here we require jQuery
- Param 4: a version for this file (optional)
- Param 5: should the script be loaded at the begining of the page or just before the closing `</body>` tag. `true` means before the closing `</body>` tag. Default `false`

Comment: For the javascript where would the existing $(document).ready(function(){ ... }) be located? is it like in the functions.php file?

Comment: no if you don't have a js file, you should create one and enqueue it.  Do you know how to do that? _edit_ Maybe check in your theme files, you might have one there already.

Comment: would it be safe to add it my jquery file since it's loaded on default?

Comment: I wouldn't do that. I updated my answer with steps to enqueue a script in WP.

Comment: There's a one little bug. It won't load the last image of the set cause the last image isn't linked since it is the last one. So when you're on the 2nd last image and you click on it, it won't load the last image.